# Unit testing not failing but hanging on subroutine call

Tags: c++

I am unit testing the following C++ code using Visual Studio 2015's built in test framework. When I run the test below, no error is thrown (and the code compiles), but the test just hangs. It only does it when the line I have commented out which calls `averageGradient` is run. Why is this?

```
float averageGradient(int x1, int x2) {
    int i = 0, y1 = 0, y2 = 0;
    while (i < graph.size() && (y1 == 0 || y2 == 0)) {     //if both y values haven't been solved then keep trying
        if (x1 >= graph[i][0] && x1 < graph[i][1]) {       // if x1 lies in the first straight line segment
            y1 = (graph[i][2] * x1) + graph[i][2];         // then calculate it's y value (y1)
        }
        else if (x2 >= graph[i][0] && x2 < graph[i][1]) {  //try the same thing for x2
            y2 = (graph[i][2] * x2) + graph[i][3];         //calculate its y value (y2)
        }
        else { i++; }                                      //otherwise incriment i to check the next straight line segment
    }
    float m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
    return m;
};
```

Unit Testing:

```
    TEST_METHOD(Average_Gradient) {
        int x1 = 683675;
        int x2 = x1 + 86400;
        //float gradient = averageGradient(x1, x2);
        float answer = 0.0000895684639;
        //Assert::AreEqual(answer, gradient);
    }
```

Comment: There is nothing to do with unit-testing. Simply, your average gradient calculation function hangs.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev OK, I'll change the tag - wasn't sure as I am really new to unit testing. However, the code does run, so why is it hanging when tested?

Comment: Does the function work properly called outside of your unit testing?

Comment: Why is there a semicolon at the end of your function?

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards Try running your method with the same values. It should hang as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an infinite loop in your code. This is not related to unit test.

```
float averageGradient(int x1, int x2) {
    int i = 0, y1 = 0, y2 = 0;
    while (i < graph.size() && (y1 == 0 || y2 == 0))    // 1
    {    
        if (x1 >= graph[i][0] && x1 < graph[i][1])      // 2
        {       
            y1 = (graph[i][2] * x1) + graph[i][2];      // 3       
        }
        else if (x2 >= graph[i][0] && x2 < graph[i][1]) // 4   
        { 
            y2 = (graph[i][2] * x2) + graph[i][3];         
        }
        else { i++; }                                      
    }
    float m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
    return m;
};
```

1. In the first iteration of your loop, let's assume that condition in line marked with `// 2` is true.
2. You enter line `// 3`, and change `y1`. `i` and `y2` are not modified.
3. Now you go to next iteration.

   - `i` hasn't changed so `i < graph.size()` is still true.
   - `y2` hasn't changed so `(y1 == 0 || y2 == 0)` is still true.
4. Thus, you go to line `// 2`: the condition is true again, as neither `x1` nor `graph[]` values have changed.
5. Execution enters `// 3`, `y1` is not modified
6. Execution continues at 3. (infinite loop)

If your first iteration enters `// 4` instead of `// 2`, the same thing happens.

You should be able to easily analyze this just by running your code under debugger.

Comment: Thank you for spotting this!